# How to set permission for a system user to particular website on plesk

Tags: linux, plesk, permissions

I'm trying to setup continuous deployment pipeline to one of the websites hosted in a Linux machine which has Plesk. A service account(service_user) is already setup there in the server(not a Plesk account though).

My issue is the service account that I mentioned above cannot access the hosting directory(/var/www/vhosts/example.com/). because it is owned by some other user & group(sysuser_9:psaserv)

The permissions details :

**Home Directory :**

[image]

**httpdocs :**

[image]

> I tried to add the service account to the following groups : psaserv &
> psacln . but still access denied.

All I need to do is copy the zip file to the hosting directory & extract it. I already messed up the directory permission of the hosting after executing chown for the service account :P . Just recreated the hosting. How do I give access to the service account to read/write to a particular hosting directory?

Comment: "owned by some other user & group"  -- What user and group is it?    What are the permissions on the `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/` directory and all parent directories?  Does it allow group `rwx`?   Do the parent directories allow group `rwx`?

Comment: Owned by sysuser_9:psaserv. The permissions what i can see is : rwx r-x ---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group `psaserv` doesn't have permission to write to `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/`.   The middle group in the permissions (`r-x`) are for the group.  The group has "read" (`r`) and "execute" (`x`) permission, but it missing the "write" (`w`) permission.   To be able to have that group be able to write to that directory, you need to change the permissions:

```
chmod g+w /var/www/vhosts/example.com/
```

After running that command, the permissions on that directory would be `rwx rwx ---`. As long as it has execute permission in each directory above that, a job running in that group would then be able to write to that directory.

Comment: Exactly!!. i noted another issue, The service account created by the systems team had Uppercase letters. So when I issue the usermod -a -G GROUP USER command I have to specify the USER in lowercase :D. i realized this after checking groups command! because the added groups was not in the list. Then applied proper write permission as Stephen specified above.